# Empty result on doctrine using DQL

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I'm trying to make this query  which return results

```
select s.code  
from clients as c 
inner join  clients_records as cr
on c.id = cr.id_client
inner join clients_survey_records as csr
on cr.id = csr.id
inner join  surveys as s
on s.id = csr.id_survey
where c.id = 50939
order by s.id DESC
limit 1;
```

in doctrine

```
$results = $qb->select($fields)
                ->from('Encueston\Entity\Client', 'c')
                ->innerJoin('Encueston\Entity\AbstractClientRecord', 'cr', 'WITH', 'c.id = cr.id')
                ->innerJoin('Encueston\Entity\ClientSurveyRecord', 'csr', 'WITH', 'cr.id = csr.id')
                ->innerJoin('Encueston\Entity\AbstractSurvey', 's', 'WITH', 's.id = csr.survey')
                ->where('c.id = :id_client')
                ->setParameter('id_client', $id)
                ->orderBy('cr.updatedAt','DESC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

but I get an empty result

Comment: try to print your sql or dql ->getQuery()->getDQL() or ->getQuery()->getSql() and try to understand the difference between your sql code

Comment: Yes but in the posted query I was testing without filter for client id

Comment: are you sure that you have good value in $id?

Comment: yes,same result(empty ) with and without $id

Comment: Post your entity mappings defined to relate them